# how to properly encode a form into json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I did this

```
let myform = $('#myapp-product-submit-form');
let jsonFormData = JSON.stringify(myform.serializeArray());
$.post( '/coaltechtest' , jsonFormData , function(datas){
```

problem:

the result contains a hundred name value pairs, e.g. written out

```
{
'name': 'product_name',
'value': 'some cool product name'
...}
```

but i want

```
{
'product_name': 'some cool product name'
}
```

Comment: You have two fields? Or is it just one?

Comment: If it;s just one, You can use `.serialize()` rather than `.serializeArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the values out.

```
let newArray = oldArray.map( item => { return { item.name: item.value}})
```

In your example oldArray is myform.serializeArray()